# Modern Python installation in home folder for scientific computing on RHEL

Tags: python, package-management, rhel-5

For various reasons, our system administrator finds Ubuntu to be too cutting-edge for our production workstation, and we have now installed [Red Hat Enterprise Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux) 5.5 (RHEL). I'm not terribly familiar with the OS but just playing around with it I noticed that many packages that I depend on for scientific computing with Python are either non-existent or horribly out-of-date.

I'm now looking to install as much as possible in my home folder. It has been simple enough to install Python and [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy), but I have been getting errors installing [SciPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy) and still need to install some other packages.

However, this isn't a question about installing any specific packages. I'm more interested in **the best method to maintain your own packages in your home folder on Linux, specifically for a Python installation**. My line of thinking is that I might need to install things like [ATLAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatically_Tuned_Linear_Algebra_Software), [Boost.Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29#Standard_library), etc. manually and would benefit from some form of package management that does not interfere with RHEL. My wish would be something like [MacPorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts), which I'm used to in Mac OS X.

Any ideas on package management in my home folder? I have a CentOS VM on Mac OS X to test with, which I understand is 100% compatible with RHEL.

**EDIT**
I think I've solved this issue now using [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) and the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository. Basically I compiled Sage into my home folder without issues (at least on CentOS) and was able to install extra Python packages that I needed (and [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29), as an added bonus).

Comment: Python comes with it's own package manager - pip ( http://pip.openplans.org/ )

Comment: pip may handle Python packages, yes, but I'm looking to include upstream non-Python dependencies as well that are either not included in RHEL or are too old to be built against for the Python packages I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what I propose would maybe be a little bit overblown but... What about a chroot environment with debian sid or ubuntu that just has python and it's dependencies and it is managed by a bulletproof manager like apt?

Comment: That sure is a bit over the top but certainly provides the most flexibility.

Comment: Yup, and nowadays with debootstrap the size and manageability is quite nice. Besides, for a production environment it provides a little bit of isolation so are less likely to damage anything inside the chroot.

Comment: Your answer is good, and I will certainly consider it for future use. Thank you.